# Why doesn't the Workflow wake up after being unloaded?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4.5

I'm trying to understand the .NET Workflow Foundation a bit better, especially how the persist / unload and resume functionality works.

So for test purposes I created a very simple Activity and attempted to host it in a `WorkflowApplication`. I'd like to learn how to use the ability to persist the workflow instances when they are idle. So I wrote the following code:

```
var store = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore("......");
var identity = new WorkflowIdentity("MyAwesomeWorkflow", Version.Parse("1.0"), String.Empty);
var activity = new Sequence()
{
    Activities =
    {
        new WriteLine() {Text = "hello"},
        new Delay() {Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)},
        new WriteLine() {Text = "bye"},
    }
};
var wfapp = new WorkflowApplication(activity, identity);
var resetEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim();
wfapp.InstanceStore = store;
wfapp.PersistableIdle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Persistable idle");
    return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
};
wfapp.Completed += delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("completed");
    resetEvent.Set();
};

wfapp.Run();
resetEvent.Wait();
```

The workflow is unloaded when the `Delay` Activity starts, but it is not resumed when the `Delay` is over. I'm not a Workflow Foundation expert, so I realize I must be using the API incorrectly. According to my collegaues, the Workflow should automatically wake up and resume execution when the `Delay` is over.

I've read [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/how-to-create-and-run-a-long-running-workflow) on the topic but it doesn't seem to explain this aspect very well.

Comment: WorkflowApplication (unlike service host) will not resume unloaded workflows for you - you have to do it manually.

Comment: @Evk Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Well not sure I can tell more. When you use WorkflowServiceHost - it can resume unloaded workflows for you. WorkflowApplication cannot, so your example works as intended, there is nothing wrong at your side.

Comment: But you can do it yourself. Workflows are persisted to database when unloaded, together with their next run time. So by polling that database you can figure out which workflows are ready to be resumed and load them. There is support for this in SqlWorkflowInstanceStore (WaitForEvents or something like that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meantime I've figured it out. Since nobody has posted an answer, I'll just post it here just in case somebody is looking for a solution.

Basically, the Workflow Engine does not support automatic resumption of workflow instances. It is misleading somewhat, but `WorkflowApplication` does not support this.

So you could:

- Manually poll the instance store database and resume the workflow instances when appropriate
- Use `WorkflowServiceHost` which implements the same polling under the hood